# How would you match two similar phone numbers in Swift, but one contains the country code and the other one does or does not

Tags: ios, regex, swift, contacts

I am trying to match two similar phone numbers in swift, but one of them is preceded by a country code and the other one can vary. 
For instance, I want these 2 phone numbers to match:

0499999999

+32499999999

I want this to be valid for any phone number all over the world. Is there a regex for this or maybe a pod I could download for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PhoneNumberKit To Parse PhoneNumber.

https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

Like :

```
let rawNumberArray = ["0291 12345678", "+49 291 12345678", "04134 1234", "09123 12345"]
let phoneNumbers = phoneNumberKit.parse(rawNumberArray)
let phoneNumbersCustomDefaultRegion = phoneNumberKit.parse(rawNumberArray, withRegion: "DE",  ignoreType: true)
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a single number. If we have lists of numbers to compare, this is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a lookup table of countries and country codes and check from the phone what their locale is

```
let countrycode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as? String

let countryPrefixes = ["IE": "+353", 
                       "US": "+1",
                        etc...

let prefix = countryPrefixes[countrycode]
```

Once you have the prefix, you should be able to look at just the remaining numbers.

Or you could use this github library https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat which seems to have that work done for you already.

Of course this is assuming that you are expecting a phone number entered into your device that is valid in the Locale that the phone is operating in.

Answer (score 0):

For the accepted answer, we need to know the region. So if we know the country code, here is a solution just to avoid any 3rd party dependency in project.

```
func isPhoneNumberEquals(_ firstNumber: String, with secondNumber: String) -> Bool {

    // If two numbers are equal directly, return true
    if firstNumber == secondNumber {
        return true
    }
    var countryCode: String? = nil
    if firstNumber.hasSuffix(secondNumber) {
        countryCode = firstNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: secondNumber, with: "")
    }
    if secondNumber.hasSuffix(firstNumber) {
        countryCode = secondNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: firstNumber, with: "")
    }
    guard let countryCode else {
    // The numbers aren't same as they don't matched with suffix
        return false
    }
    if countryCode == myCountryCode {
    // The country code and the phone number without country code both are matched for the given numbers.
        return true
    }
    let digitDifference = myCountryCode.replacingOccurrences(of: countryCode, with: "")
    // Sometimes there is a common '0' in phone number and country code. If this is not the case, return false
    return digitDifference == "0"
}
```

Note: If you find any corner case, please comment down below. We will resolve/improve our production code as well :P.